# Why is my parallel std::for_each only using 1 thread?

Tags: c++, foreach, parallel-processing, c++17

I'm trying to parallelize this C++ code (computing a continuous Fourier transform of points, modeled as Dirac impulses), and this code compiles and works correctly, but it only uses 1 thread. Is there something else I need to do to get multiple threads working? This is on a Mac with 4 cores (8 threads), compiled with GCC 10.

```
vector<double> GetFourierImage(const Point pts[],
                               const int num_samples,
                               const int res,
                               const double freq_step) {
  vector<double> fourier_img(res*res, 0.0);
  double half_res = 0.5 * res;

  vector<int> rows(res);
  std::iota(rows.begin(), rows.end(), 0);
  std::for_each(  // Why doesn't this parallelize?
      std::execution::par_unseq,
      rows.begin(), rows.end(),
      [&](int i) {
    double y = freq_step * (i - half_res);
    for (int j = 0; j < res; j++) {
      double x = freq_step * (j - half_res);

      double fx = 0.0, fy = 0.0;
      for (int pt_idx = 0; pt_idx < num_samples; pt_idx++) {
        double dot = (x * pts[pt_idx].x) + (y * pts[pt_idx].y);
        double exp = -2.0 * M_PI * dot;
        fx += cos(exp);
        fy += sin(exp);
      }
      fourier_img[i*res + j] = sqrt((fx*fx + fy*fy) / num_samples);
    }
  });

  return fourier_img;
}
```

Comment: I have not looked into this for sure, but it is entirely possible that gcc has not yet implemented `std::execution::par_unseq`, this is what this sounds like. The symbol is defined but it does ...nothing.

Comment: `par_unseq` tells the compiler that it *may* use parallelism, but doesn't *have* to. Googling around, I found a mailinglist entry (2017) that talked about preliminary implementation of `par_unseq` on top of `#pragma omp`. If that implementation has been merged in gcc 10, it is likely that you have to enable OpenMP for that to work. Looking at  https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html, it looks like you need "Thread Building Blocks" (whatever that is) for `std::execution`

Comment: Oh, hmm, okay, thank you both. I installed Thread Building Blocks (TBB) and added -ltbb to my compile command which should link it, but it still doesn't seem to be using more than one thread...

Comment: How many items are you iterating over? t may not bother launching a new thread if the number is small.

Comment: @Andrew So HAL mentioned both OpenMP and TBB.  And you only mentioned TBB.  Did you not understand, miss it, or ?

Comment: @Galik - the code above typically loops over 1024 elements. I tried combining the two loops into 1024*1024, and still didn't work.

Comment: @Adam - Sorry I didn't mention that. I think that GCC 10 has OpenMP installed (but not enabled) by default? I was compiling with both -fopenmp and -ltbb. However, I decided to test this by actually trying either an OpenMP parallel for loop, or a TBB parallel_for, and *neither* seem to work. With TBB it can't find the headers. OpenMP compiles, but crashes with "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _GOMP_parallel", so it doesn't seem like it's actually linking it (I set both -fopenmp and -lgomp). Seems like we're getting somewhere...

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue

Comment: I am sorry, I never did.

Comment: I linked with `-ltbb`, and it worked.  (Arch Linux, g++ 12.2.0, tbb 2021.5.0-2)

Answer (score 3):

In GCC 9, there was a hard dependency to TBB when using the different executions policies, if that were not present then the build would fail. That changed in GCC 10 (and present in GCC 11), where if the library was not present then the for_each would default to a sequential loop. This can be seen at https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-10.1.0/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/c++config#L679. To fix your issue, try linking to TBB with `-ltbb`. This resolved the same issue you were having on Ubuntu 20.04 using GCC 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on macOS. In my case, adding the path to the tbb header files to the include search path resolved the problem. For g++-11 and tbb installed with homebrew this was `g++-11 -O3 -std=c++17 -I/opt/homebrew/include -o main main.cpp -ltbb`; this directory contains a tbb header folder. If I do not add this flag, my code compiled but ran only single-threaded, as described by @Andrew.  In my case, adding the `-fopenmp` flag was not necessary, but the `-ltbb` is, as pointed out by @Ryan H.